# QTcreator hugely faster than Visual Studio

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, qt-creator

I have an image processing application that i firstly coded with QTcreator and Opencv in 32 bits mode (i have a 64 bits processor, Windows 7 64 bits). When i run the application, sometimes, i have this error: Opencv failed to allocate X bytes. In order to overcome this limitation, i switched to visual studio 2012 and i run the application in 64 bits mode. I also integrated the QT Library (because i use qthread and other qt classes) and of course opencv to VS2012. The problem is that visual studio is very slow comparing to qtcreator:

QTcreator (Debug: 0.826s, Release: 0.265s)
Visual Studio (Debug: 130.463s, Release: 4.15s)

i don't understand this huge difference.

Comment: Wrong question. Qt Creator and Visual Studio are IDEs that in the end use the same compiler (unless you use something like MinGW with Qt Creator). First of all, are you compiling both binaries you're comparing in release mode?

Comment: Without at least some vague notion of the code involved, it's doubtful any of us can really understand the difference either. Needless to say, while there are frequently some differences in speed between gcc and VC++, a difference this large is quite rare -- to the point that it's likely a difference in how you're using the tools.

Comment: Are you using C API of opencv? Failed to allocate ... bytes error comes when you have a memory leak (if you are not releasing the structures you are creating in a loop). If you use C++ API the memory management is automatically done.

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı I think i am using the c++ API. But Failed to allocate can also comes from the memory limitation of 32 bits applications. i noted that this error occurs when over than 5.7 go of memory are reserved (i have 32go of memory)

Comment: There is a memory limit for 32 bit apps, but still it should allow you to build a reasonable one. I would try and optimize my code, or check memory leaks before I attempt anything else.

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı In my application i have 8 threads running at the same time. Each one of them try to build several learning models using Random Forests algorithm. Thus, the Memory requirements are big. I use an object instantiated from CvRTrees class in each thread and i free it (Delete CvRTrees_object) at the end. I don't think i have Memory leaks